# exchange server 2007 drive space problem

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I have an exchange server that is running out of space but it doesn't look to be related to active mailboxes. The .edb database file is 69GB but when I run the command:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | ft DisplayName,@{label="TotalItemSize(MB)";expression={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}},ItemCount
```

I find that only 12GB of mailboxes are on this exchange server. Why is the database file far larger than what the actual user mailboxes are?

Answer (score 3):

That's because databases contain more than just active mails, they also can contain deleted mails being kept per policy. Additionally, databases do not shrink; once they reach a size they never shrink unless you do an *offline* shrink process on them. It could very well be the case that your users had lots of space on them once upon a time.

Also, your log-files can consume quite a bit of space. You don't mention if they're on the same volume or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The log files account for 45.8GB by themselves. If I were to archive the log files and delete them would that impact Exchange on its ability to run.

Comment: @ShaneLayton The best thing is to run a backup, as that empties the log-files. That's impact-free as far as Exchange is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not performing a regularly occurring Full backup of the Information Store with an Exchange aware backup program. My suggestion would be to implement such or turn on circular logging.

Answer (score 0):

I also having the same problem at the moment now, and just realize that **Circular logging** is not designed for truncating log, and Microsoft don't recommend us flush the log by this way.

Here it is a related articles for you:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124515(EXCHG.80).aspx